# Change width of an element dynamically when its content changes

Tags: html, css

I have a div includes 6 inputs. that display of two of them is "none" and when I click on a checkbox these two inputs display will be "inline".
I want my div width change and increase when the other two inputs come. 
html :

```html
<div class="row" id="row1">
  <input class="input" id="material_name" value="Material" />
  <input class="input" id="material_name" value="Material" />
  <input class="input" id="unit" value="Unit" />
  <input class="input" id="count" value="11" />
  <input class="input" id="unit_price" placeholder="Unit Price" />
  <input class="input" id="total_price" placeholder="Total Price" />
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document - right now, you are using `id="material_name"` twice. Fix that. Then, change whatever currently makes your hidden inputs “come” with code that does one thing, and one thing only: Toggle a class on the parent div container element. Use that class in your stylesheet to give the div the desired width, _and_ to make the inputs in question get `display: inline` (keyword: descendant combinator.)

Comment: What happens currently - do they not increase the divs width? if not is that because the div is already 100% width and the inputs just wrap?  If the div isn't 100% then please show your current css too.  Also, if the div becomes larger the the width of the screen, what do you want to happen?

Answer (score -2):

`div` is block-line element, but `span` is inline. If you need to change it with `html` you can replace `div` tag with `span`, otherwise changing the `display` of `div`, made it to behave like span. By default, the `width` property of block-line element, is not depend on its `innerHTML`, but for inline element the `width` property changes with its inner element's width

`#row1{
        display:inline-block;
    }`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer might be correct, but you'll find it's better appreciated if you include some explanation about what it's doing and how it will help to solve the OPs problem. Additionally, and I'm not a CSS guy, but I suspect `diaplay` contains a typo?

Comment: Agree with previous commenter as it is technically correct (if you fix the typo), but if you can expand upon the answer and explain why, the OP might better understand why and hopefully pass that knowledge along to others one day.